# Date in Java not converting to sql properly

Tags: java, sql

My date (s) is not being formatted properly for sql, any ideas why?

```
public void vDate(String s) {
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
            java.util.Date utilDate = (Date)dateFormat.parse(s);
            date = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        }catch(Exception e){
            edate = "Please enter a valid date!";
            valid = false;
        }
    }
```

date is of type java.sql.Date.
20-03-2012 is converted to 2013-08-03

Comment: oddly enough, not mentioned below:  use `dd-MM-yyyy` for your SimpleDateFormat() format string if the input is 20-03-2012.

Answer (score 2):

You're using MM-dd-yyyy, but passing in 20-03-2012.  20 is not a valid month.  You should us dd-MM-yyyy instead, if you want to pass the day first.  Alternatively, add sanity checks for the month... if the inputted value is <= 0 or >= 13, then reject it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Your date format is `MM-dd-yyyy`, and your date is `20-03-2012`. There are only 12 months in a year, not 20.

Answer (score 0):

20 is taken as month because of SDF provided by you. Which converts year to be 2013 (12+8=20). Please check/change it.

Answer (score 0):

`20-03-2012` is not in the `"MM-dd-yyyy"` so it tried to interpret it as month #20. There's no such a month, so you get shifted by 1 year and 8 months, thus you get `2013-08-03` (3 is the day part).